# Nodejs async functions callbacks wrong execution order

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I have a problem regarding doing several "slow functions", and I dont know how to get my value after everyone of them is done..

I'll print some code for you to see.
This is my test route that want to retrieve stuff from the function `getUploadedMovies` and then each of those objects want to get more info from the function `getMovieInfo` that is pushing the result from both function calls into an array.

My problem is that this array only contain the quickest run of the function, not all objects...

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {

```
allinfo = [];

        getUploadedMovies("hej", function(data){

            data.forEach(function(object){

                getMovieInfo(object.imdb_id, function(omdb){

                    omdb.forEach(function(content) {
                        allinfo.push({

                            "title" : content.title,
                            "year" : content.year,
                            "bpmvalue" : object.bpmvalue,
                        });

                    });
                    res.send(allinfo);

                });

            }); 

        });

    });
```

The other functions that get the info are these:

```
function getUploadedMovies(user, callback){

    console.log('Getting Uploaded movies for user');

    Upload.find({user_id : "117455612749622948262"}, function(err, info){
        var allmovies = [];
        info.forEach(function(object) {
            allmovies.push(object);

        })

    callback(allmovies);
    return;

    })

}

function getMovieInfo(value, callback) {

    omdb.get( value, true, function(err, movie){

        console.log('getting info for '+movie.title);

        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        if(!movie) {
            return console.log('No movie found');
        }

        var moviedata = [];
        globalshit = movie.imdb.id;
        moviedata.push({
                "title" : movie.title,
                "year" : movie.year,
                "plot" : movie.plot,
                "rating" : movie.imdb.rating,
                "votes" : movie.imdb.votes,
                "runtime" : movie.runtime,
                "actors" : movie.actors,
                "director" : movie.director,
                "writers" : movie.writers,
                "id" : movie.imdb.id

         });

        callback(moviedata);
        return;
    });
}
```

I want to send `allinfo` to another page to show the data. But I can only get one objects data in allinfo...

This is what res.send(allinfo) shows:
[image]

Thanksful for all help! :)

Comment: Well, as you said your self, `getMovieInfo` is **asynchronous**. And you are calling `res.send(allinfo);` in the first iteration of `data.forEach`. You have to call it after you are done iterating over `data`.

Comment: Yeah, but it wont work after. It calls it before the method even starts..

Answer (score 0):

For each loop of async functions, you track which (or how many) have finished. You can do that by simply counting the async functions as they finish, and by checking whether everything is done yet or not. If so, you invoke the next step.

```
let done = 0
let allData = []

urls.forEach((url) => {
  $.get(url).done((data) => {
    allData.push(data)
    done++ // Increment done
    if (done === urls.length) {
      whateverComesNext(allData)
    }
  })
})
```